# Удаление существующего функционала, которое не влечет за собой несовместимость с предыдущей версией

Tags: контроль-версий

Есть, скажем, какой-то код, который в определенных случаях выбрасывает в консоль предупреждения. Эти предупреждения никак не влияют на работу программы, а просто предупреждают пользователя о том, что он что-то сделал не так.

Если я в дальнейшем решу отказаться от вывода этих предупреждений, то каким будет считаться это изменение с точки зрения [semver](https://semver.org/)'а? Мажорным, минорным или патчем?

На сайте вроде написано так:

> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
>   MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
>   PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes

То есть

> MAJOR версия, когда вы делаете обратно-несовместимые изменения

Не подходит. Все будет работать так, как и работало.

> MINOR версия, когда вы добавляете какой-то обратно-совместимый функционал

Я не добавляю, а удаляю. Или это одно и то же с точки зрения semver'а?

> PATCH версия, когда фиксите баги (и при этом ничего не ломается)

Ну это, вроде, однозначно не подходит.

В общем, что выбрать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. на работу программы Вы не сильно влияете, т.е. просто убираете предпреждающие сообщения - следовательно это MINOR обновление.